# Removing character after retrieving from database

Tags: c#

I would like to remove first two chatracter of a string but it is not working. Can i know why was this issue

```
       while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                sqlNew = sqlNew + "', '" + rdr.GetString(0);
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }           
        }

        if (!(sqlNew == ""))
        {
            sqlNew = sqlNew + "'";
            sqlNew.Substring(2);
        }

        textBox1.Text = sqlNew;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Substring` doesn't modify the string (since strings are immutable), it returns a new string with the result, so:

```
sqlNew = sqlNew.Substring(2);
```